# Same form, different pages

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms

I have a simple form, and when i submit the information, i insert it on my DB. Until here everything is ok. But i need to have the same form on 20 pages. I know i could replicate the code, or even use different buttons to get the result i want. But i want to know if there is a better way to use the same form, and identify the page where i submit the information. So that the information on my DB could be:

ID
Page 
Name
Email
Text
and so on...

Thank you in advance. 
Best Regards.

"Maybe i didn't explain myself well, and i'm not asking for "free coding service" as someone said. I know i can , in the different pages. That is what i'm doing. Also the information is being inserted on my BD when i submit. No problem until here! What i want to know, is how can i have my form being include on the different pages, using the same  "submit" button with the same name, but when the information is inserted on my BD, i can know that my column "page" gets the right information from the different pages."

Comment: plenty of options; what did you try?

Comment: I for one do not write out code. Come back when you have something to show and may have failed you. Stack isn't a free coding service.

Comment: To begin with create one separate page with the form. Then you could INCLUDE that form in all other pages.

Comment: Did your question get answered ( if so, select one) or are you stuck on something?(In that case we might be able to help you further). If you're still stuck you might want to explain what you tried and what problem you're having specifically (:

Comment: Maybe i didn't explain myself well, and i'm not asking for "free coding service" as someone said. I know i can <php include my form ?>, in the different pages. That is what i'm doing. Also the information is being inserted on my BD when i submit. No problem until here! What i want to know, is how can i have my form being include on the different pages, using the same  "submit" button with the same name, but when the information is inserted on my BD, i can know that my column "page" gets the right information from the different pages.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, i figure it out!

If i use:

```
     $current_page = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

    if($current_page == 'try.php') {
      $current_page = 'try1';
    }

    if($current_page == 'try_2.php') {
      $current_page = 'try2';
    }

   $page = $current_page;

if($submit) {
    mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO `DB` (page) VALUES ('$page') ")
}
```

I can get the result i want.

Thank you anyway! :)

Answer (score 0):

Something that I use for every website I create, is building my own "Template" page in the root folder, and create a page like index.php etc 
. in the same root folder.

In those "page" files I include everything that i need.
Inside the root folder I have a content and classes folder.

The "content" files contain things that will be shown on the page and the menu that I need on many pages, and I use the class files for things that need to be handled, like DB connection and form handling.

Example of me including content inside the template page between the `<body></body>` tags

```
 <?php
      if(isset($content)) {
         include_once $content;
      }
  ?>
```

And the example of index.php

```
<?php
//Defining page title
define('WEBSITE_TITLE', 'Website title');

//breadcrumb
define('BREADCRUMB', '');

//Content location
$content = 'content/index.php';

//Database connection
include_once 'classes/db-connect.php';

//Sessions
include_once 'classes/session.php';

//Including website template
include_once 'template.php';
?>
```

Using this method makes everything less time consuming because easier to change one thing for multiple pages that are basically the same.

You can use this for example for your form.

Answer (score -1):

I would make a class that in turn calls a template.

The class will hold properties appropriate to its instantiation and can be as flexible as needed.  The template will be called from this class.

You can then instantiate it on your pages as something like:

```
<?php
    $oHandle = new MyFormClass("specialinfo 1", "maybe a second");
    echo($oHandle->theRenderedHtmlForm);
?>
```

of course I did not write out the class for you, but it is simple enough and my answer fits the question for level of detail.

I hope it helps.